# Why can't I transfer my Pokemon from GBA to DS?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I am encountering a problem transferring my Pokemon via the GBA slot in my Nintendo DS. I already checked that they are the same language and have the official Nintendo seal. Also, I've verified that my DS is real and that both cards have been inserted correctly.

What could cause my game to display the "Please insert Pokemon [all gba games] to enter" error?

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Won't transfer or enter pal park it just says "please insert pokemon (all gba games) to enter

Comment: If either answer has solved or at least clarified your issue can you please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same combination of DS card and GBA Cartridge? or are you trying different combinations?

Example: You are trying Diamond with Ruby. Have you got any alternative GBA or DS cartridges to test? Diamond and [any other GBA game] or [Any other DS game] and Ruby. As if a different game works, it's a cartridge issue; however if ANY combination won't work, it's a hardware or contact issue.

Is the DS detecting the GBA game in the slot when you start the console? as that's a key element, it needs to know it's there on startup. Can you play the GBA game on the DS at all? Can you save the game? Is the Clock running on the GBA game (potentially berry glitch or battery)?

If it reads the GBA game and can play it, i can't see any reason why it can't transfer to the DS - as it can obviously read and write from both slots if you can launch, load from, and save to both.

If a single cartridge combo won't work, there's the issue - check the GBA cartrdge contacts. If no combos work, or you can't launch/read from/write to any GBA game - then there's your issue, your DS's GBA reader is faulty. Check the contacts inside the DS then consider that the port itself may be dead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for dust in the GBA slot. If that doesn't work, look for out-of-place looking pieces in the slot, and if none of those work, you're gonna want to send it in to a shop or Nintendo.

EDIT: You could always borrow a friend's DS or rent one if available.

Comment: I did all that except for shop but that cost ALOT sometimes